# Get token price on BSC with solidity

Tags: solidity

sorry if i had to ask this question here, but i didn't find any forums about BSC, also i know that ethereum and bsc have the same architecture and language.

I need to find the price pair of some token on BSC

i already found some code on reddit to find the price pair on uniswap, i know pancakeswap is a fork of uniswap so i thought it was good but it doesn't work

I imported in my smart contract IBEP20.sol and IpancakeswapV2Pair.sol

this is my code:

```
function getTokenPrice(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint)
   {
    IPancakeswapV2Pair pair = IPancakeswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
    IBEP20 token1 = IBEP20(pair.token1);
    (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();

    // decimals
    uint res0 = Res0*(10**token1.decimals());
    return((amount*res0)/Res1); // return amount of token0 needed to buy token1
   }
```

always returns 0

Answer (score 1):

Because `(amount*res0)/Res1` on your return line will result in a floating point number, like 0.0256 or something. Solidity/ETH/BSC doesn't support this number type.
Lets say amount is 95, Res0 is 12000, and Res1 is 75000. This results in 15.2.

We need to multiply the answer to a point where we can get enough digits to be accurate. In this example, we only need to multiply it by 10 to get an integer (152).
But we all know blockchains love their huge decimal points, so probably safer to multiply it by a factor of 1,000,000 or more. Then even if the price answer is like 0.04658814, it'll result in an int of 46588.14, which will be rounded to 46588. If you know to divide that answer by 1,000,000 - then you'll know your final answer is 0.046588 (Which is close enough).

Comment: I always multiplies by 1 eth (18 decimals) & then divide by 1 eth. In such a way I get the best precision.
   Eg: (amount * res0) / Res1 -> (((amount * res0) * 1 ether) / Res1) / 1 ether

Unit tests are a big pain for such precision, I use this calc - https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculator-precision.html